# How to pass $scope to $factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Im new in angular js and I want to pass my empty $scope to my $factory for the dynamic login im using the $http to get the data in my API i tried to put the scope in the factory but i didn't work

**This is my serviceAPI**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('starter').factory(serviceAPI', function($http, $q, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {



        function getData() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Loading...' });
            var url = "myAPI";

            var data = {
                username: "admin", <-- this is the one I want to dynamic it
                password: "admin" <--
            };

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data


            }).success(function(data) {

                $ionicLoading.hide();
                deferred.resolve(data);

            }).error(function() {
                console.log('Error while making HTTP call');
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                deferred.reject();

            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }


        //a Return value to public
        return {
            getData: getData,


        };


    })

}());
```

**this is the controller**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('starter').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'serviceAPI', LoginCtrl]);


    function LoginCtrl($scope, serviceAPI) {
     $scope.username = "";
     $scope.password = "";
        $scope.login = function() {

            serviceAPI.getData().then(function(data) {

                console.log(data)
            });

        }


    }

}());
```

Comment: What $scope ? You are not passing scope anywhere in the above code.
Anyways, passing scope is not a good practice. What is it that you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Your controller is responsible for gluing together your view and data layer.
Your view and data layer should be unaware of each other. Meaning that passing the scope to your factory would violate the MVC architecture by creating dependencies between your view and data layer.
So just fill up your scope inside of your controller where you are currently logging your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at service api

```
function getData(userNameIn, passwordIn) {
//...
var data = {
username: userNameIn,
password: passwordIn
};   //...}
```

at controller
...

```
$scope.username = "";
$scope.password = "";
$scope.login = function() {            
serviceAPI.getData($scope.username,$scope.password).then(function(data) {
console.log(data)
});

}
```

...